# Can't I call a __host__ __device__ function from a __device__ function?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

In CUDA documentation I found that cudaDeviceGetAttribute is a `__host__ __device__` function. So I thought I could call it in my `__global__` function to get some attributes of my device. Sadly it seems to mean something different because I get an compile error event if I put it into a `__device__` function and call this one from my global.

Is it possible to call cudaDeviceGetAttribute on my GPU? or what else does `__host__ __device__` mean?

Here is my source code:

```
__device__ void GetAttributes(int* unique)
{
    cudaDeviceAttr attr = cudaDevAttrMaxThreadsPerBlock;
    cudaDeviceGetAttribute(unique, attr, 0);
}


__global__ void ClockTest(int* a, int* b, long* return_time, int* unique)
{
    clock_t start = clock();

    //some complex calculations

    *a = *a + *b;
    *b = *a + *a;

    GetAttributes(unique);

    *a = *a + *b - *a;

    clock_t end = clock();
    *return_time = end - start;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    long time = 0;
    int uni;

    int* dev_a;
    int* dev_b;
    long* dev_time;
    int* unique;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

        cudaMalloc(&dev_a, sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc(&dev_b, sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc(&dev_time, sizeof(long));
        cudaMalloc(&unique, sizeof(int));

        cudaMemcpy(dev_a, &a, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(dev_b, &b, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        ClockTest <<<1,1>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_time, unique);

        cudaMemcpy(&a, dev_a, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(&time, dev_time, sizeof(long), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(&uni, unique, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        cudaFree(&dev_a);
        cudaFree(&dev_b);
        cudaFree(&dev_time);
        cudaFree(&unique);

        printf("%d\n", time);
        printf("unique: %d\n", uni);

        cudaDeviceReset();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to get that info in CUDA code? Why can't you call from the CPU and pass into the GPU?

Comment: I know that I could pass it from CPU, but for my project it is necessary that the information is gathered in the device itself for security reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** sorry, my previous answer was not correct.  There does seems to be a problem in `nvcc` (see below).

`cudaDeviceGetAttribute` can work correctly in device code, here is a worked example on K20X, CUDA 8.0.61:

```
$ cat t1305.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void tkernel(){

  int val;
  cudaError_t err = cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&val, cudaDevAttrMaxThreadsPerBlock, 0);
  printf("err = %d, %s\n", err, cudaGetErrorString(err));
  printf("val = %d\n", val);

}


int main(){

  tkernel<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1305 t1305.cu -rdc=true -lcudadevrt
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1305
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
err = 0, no error
val = 1024
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

There are [various runtime API functions supported for use in device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference).
For the supported runtime API functions, it's generally necessary to:

1. compile for a cc 3.5 or higher device
2. compile with relocatable device code
3. link against the cuda device runtime library

In addition, your code has some other coding errors in that we do not pass the address of the pointer to `cudaFree`, just the pointer itself.

Caveats for this particular function:

1. There appears to be a problem in the CUDA compiler that if this device runtime API call is used without any other runtime API call in the kernel code, then the code generation will not happen correctly.  The workaround at this time is to make sure your kernel contains at least one other cuda runtime API call.  In my above example I used `cudaGetErrorString`, but you could e.g. use `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or anything else, I think.  I have filed an internal NVIDIA bug to report this issue.
2. There appears to be a documentation error in the list of device runtime API calls supported in the CDP section of the programming guide (link above).  The function `cudaGetDeviceProperty` does not exist, but I believe it should refer to `cudaDeviceGetAttribute`.  I have filed an internal NVIDIA bug for this documentation error.

Comment: I've updated my answer - there were a couple things wrong with it.

Comment: Robert, I think your answer should be split off into a separate question+answer about the general issue of calling runtime API functions from device code, and here you should leave just the mention of the bug and a link to the general question+answer. This will also allow us to rename the question to mention cudaDeviceGetAttribute() specifically. I don't mind doing it myself if you want.

Comment: Since OP: 1. Did not demonstrate proper CUDA error checking (which in any event would have flagged an issue)  2. Did not provide the actual compile command  3. Did not indicate which device they are running on 4. Did not indicate whether my update addressed the issue they were having  I don't agree with going in a different direction with this answer.  It is sufficient for both purposes that you mention.  You are of course, welcome to ask whatever question you wish on SO.  There *does seem* to be a bug in `nvcc`, but it's not actually clear that it is the root cause of OP's issue.